# Inequality Integral who involves logarithms and exponentials

Tags: calculus, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, integral-inequality

> Show that: $$\int_1^e (x^2+1)\log^n(x) dx \leq \frac{2}{e^{n+1}} \int_1^e e^x\cdot x^n dx$$

My approach: I tried using Cauchy-Swartz but not work. I tried $\log(x) \leq x, \forall x \geq 1$ but still not work.
Any ideas? :/ I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that we have the inequalities 
$$\log(x)\le x/e$$
and 
$$2e^{x-1}\ge (x^2+1)$$ 
And we are done!

---

To show that $\log(x)\le x/e$, we use the inequality $\log(x)\le x-1$.  Letting $y=x/e$, we find that

$$\begin{align}
\log(x)&=\log(ey)\\\\
&=\log(y)+1\\\\
&\le (y-1)+1\\\\
&=y\\\\
&=x/e
\end{align}$$

---

To show that $2e^{x-1}\ge (x^2+1)$, we write $x^2+1=2+2(x-1)+(x-1)^2$.  Then, observe that

$$\begin{align}
2e^{x-1}&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{2(x-1)^k}{k!}\\\\
&=2+2(x-1)+(x-1)^2+\underbrace{\sum_{k=3}^\infty \frac{2(x-1)^k}{k!}}_{\ge 0}\\\\
&\ge x^2+1
\end{align}$$